# Are there alternatives to deriving classes from LINQ to SQL joins and [Table] mappings?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Pardon the length, please. Also, this is a completely hypothetical, off-the-cuff situation and code samples should not be scrutinized for complete accuracy.

So, .Net plays nice when you have a simple, straightforward LINQ:

```
Invoice tbl_invoice = from invoice in DbContext.Invoice 
                      where invoice.RecordID == 1 
                      select invoice;
```

Assuming there is an Invoice class as follows:

```
[Table]
public class Invoice
{
    [Column]
    public int RecordID {get; set;}

    [Column]
    public DateTime RecordDate {get; set;}
}
```

Given the execution of the sample LINQ, the above class would be instanced with the appropriate values in the attributed Column properties.

Let's advance the query a bit:

```
var purchases = (from invoice in DbContext.Invoice 
                 join order in DbContext.Order on invoice.RecordID equals order.InvoiceID 
                 select new ProductPurchase 
                 { 
                     invoice.RecordID, 
                     invoice.RecordDate, 
                     order.PartID, 
                     order.Quantity 
                 })
                .ToList();    // this is used to create a BindingList<ProductPurchase>
```

There must be two classes that resemble the following:

```
[Table]
public class Order
{
    [Column]
    public int InvoiceID {get; set;}

    [Column]
    public string OrderID {get; set;}

    [Column]
    public string Quantity {get; set;}
}

[Table]
public class ProductPurchase : Invoice
{
    [Column]
    public int InvoiceID {get; set;}

    [Column]
    public string PartID {get; set;}

    [Column]
    public string Quantity {get; set;}
}
```

The goal in the second sample is to create a `BindingList<T>` so that the data can be used as a DataSource. So with the second LINQ sample we could do the following:

```
BindingList<ProductPurchase> purchases = new BindingList<ProductPurchase>(purchases);
```

We cannot do this as easily as it seems. We must inherit concrete classes in order for this to work. In my opinion, this is highly inelegant. I thought, *it sure would be nice if I could create an interface.* Something like:

```
[Table]
public interface IInvoice
{
    [Column]
    public int RecordID {get; set;}

    [Column]
    public DateTime RecordDate {get; set;}
}
```

Now, assume there is a similar IOrder interface, I could create a ProductPurchase concrete class as follows:

```
[Table]
public class ProductPurchase : IInvoice, IOrder
{  }
```

...**IF** the `[TableAttribute()]` were allowed on interfaces.

Let's say I want to include a `join` to the PartID in tblParts that would retrieve a PartsDescription and PartsCost; only one base (concrete or abstract) class can be inherited. It seems like you have to create a bunch of junk derivations to be able to accommodate the joins. Is there an alternative? I grow weary of using DataTable/DataView as the data source to a DataGridView. It would be much simpler to be able to use the classes I've created as mappings.

One example of a task I am trying to complete:

1. List records in DataGridView
   displaying certain joined data.
2. User double-clicks the selected datagrid row view.
3. New WinForm displays queried info now from several joined tables

In step 2, when the user selects an Invoice, I convert the DataGridRowView to a DataRow. Not so bad, really. But when I finish the query, I have an anonymous datatype which can be used to instance a new DataTable and populate the values of the DataRow.

Binding the DataRow to the new WinForm is not as straightforward as binding a class. Thus my question and curiosity about alternatives. Any ideas would be helpful.

**EDIT:**
A couple of links that explain a little more:

- [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/AnonymousTypeTransform.aspx)
- [Linq2Sql - Explicit Construction of Entity Exception](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/04/25/linq2sql-explicit-construction-of-entity-exception.aspx)

**EDIT 2:**
Let's say I have a query from 3 tables:

**tblInvoices**:
        InvoiceID | InvoiceDate | Balance | Paid | PaidDate

**tblPurchaseItem**:
        PartNumber | InvoiceID | PartCost| PartDescription

**tblInventory**:
        PartNumber | OnHands | ReOrder | Restock

Assume there are 3 classes decorated with [Table] mapping attribute with all appropriate [Column] mapping attributes { get; set; }.

I may have a method resembling the following:

```
public static BindingList<InvoiceDetails> GetInvoiceDetails (int InvoiceID)
{
    // LINQ is probably incorrect - feel free to post corrections :)
    IList<InvoiceDetails> invDetails = (from purchItems in DbContext.PurchaseItemsMap 
                                        join invoices in DbContext.Invoices 
                                            on purchItems.InvoiceID equals invoices.InvoiceID
                                        join invItems in DbContext.InventoryItemsMap
                                            on purchItems.PartNumber equals invItems.PartNumber
                                        where purchItems.InvoiceID == InvoiceID
                                        where invItems.Restock == true
                                        select new InvoiceDetails
                                        {
                                            invoices.InvoiceID,
                                            purchItems.PartDescription,
                                            purchItems.PartCost,
                                            invItems.OnHands
                                        })
                                        .ToList();

    return new BindingList(invDetails);
}
```

In order for this to work I would need the following:

```
[Table]
public class InvoiceDetails : PurchaseItems
{  // invoices column getters & setters  }

[Table]
public class PurchaseItems : InventoryItems
{  // purchasItems column getters & setters  }

[Table]
public class InventoryItems
{  // inventoryItems column getters & setters  }
```

Now, which is more nonsensical? Having to create weird combinations of class derivations that would create a maintenance nightmare; or, hypothetically, create interfaces for table mappings and simply derive classes like InvoiceDetails as follows:

```
public class InvoiceDetails : IInventoryItems, IPurchaseItems, IInvoices
{    }
```

Comment: IMO, allowing a `[Table]` attribute on an interface is completely nonsensical.  Interfaces are not entities.  But entites *can* implement interfaces.  Can you elaborate a bit more on what you were hoping to achieve by adding the attribute to an interface?  I'm afraid I didn't understand your example to that effect.

Comment: @Kirk: I suspect that that there is some form of instancing going on and some reflection being performed and that is why the Table Attribute cannot be used. Otherwise, I wouldn't really consider the notion nonsensical.

Comment: it's just that the `[Table]` attribute indicates to LinqToSql that it is a class that into which it must *materialize* data from a data reader.   This requires instantiation, and obviously you cannot instantiate an interface.  That is what confuses me.

Comment: @Kirk: However, a concrete class implementing an interface with the [Table] attribute *can* have that attribute extended onto itself; therefore, the concrete class has the [Table] attribute. MS didn't see fit to design the TableAttribute that way. So, again, I'm looking for alternatives to the junk-ugly, whackidoo derivations you have to go through to get a concrete class.  :)

Comment: i dont't know about the attributes, but you can construct proxy-classes via duck typing: http://www.deftflux.net/blog/page/Duck-Typing-Project.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often you can make use of an anonymous class, and save some of the headache of this.

However, when you want to make use of it as an explicit type, then you can indeed use an interface. However, you do not need to make the interface marked as `[Table]`. Your example of:

```
[Table]
public interface IInvoice
{
    [Column]
    public int RecordID {get; set;}

    [Column]
    public DateTime RecordDate {get; set;}
}

[Table]
public class ProductPurchase : IInvoice, IOrder
{  }
```

Can work perfectly well as:

```
public interface IInvoice
{
    public int RecordID {get; set;}

    public DateTime RecordDate {get; set;}
}

[Table]
public class ProductPurchase : IInvoice, IOrder
{  }
```

After all, `[Table]` and `[Column]` are only of use to the Linq2SQL code itself in producing the mappings between database and .NET and the code that retrieves them, etc. Code acting on the objects in any other way don't care about those attributes. Hence, code can operate on an `IInvoice` whether the implementing class is `[Table]` or not.

Comment: +1: I don't have time to try this out. It makes sense so I will award the bounty. I can't believe I was so close to having it figured out. In your opinion, does the need for derivation seem real and useful or am I over-complicating things?

Comment: I've used it in the past, though I did find that some of the times I was indeed over-complicating and refactored it out again later, but sometimes it was indeed useful.

Comment: In my specific project, I have several instances where I am pulling data from at least 3 tables. It is very convenient to be able to write my LINQ with a `select new DerivedClass (params).ToList()`. The results can then be used as a DataSource to a DataGridView. This means that I can convert a DataGridRowView right back to my concrete class avoiding all the DataTable/DataView and DataRow hurdles.